# SQL Server - alternative to sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats that isn't wiped on server restart?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to collect data on user interactions (read, CREATE/ALTER, INSERT etc.) with my database, to see which schemas and tables are still in use by people. The closest thing to what I need that I've come across is `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`. However, this data is wiped every time the server is restarted, which happened two weeks ago (so I assume it is a frequent occurrence).

I am looking for a permanent equivalent, or at the very least, I need to see what is happening over more than a month. The best answer I have right now is to take a daily snapshot of `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` in case it gets wiped, and piece it together in a few weeks, but this is tedious. Is there a permanent log, and if not, why can't this data be captured long-term?

One more thing is that I would like to see more than just 'last read' because this might give a false positive (e.g. if someone accidentally clicked the wrong table, so I would think it is in use, when actually nobody has properly used it in years). Are there any ideas for this question?

Comment: What I do for ephemeral DMV data I want to retain and analyze is insert periodic snapshots into a user table, along with a collection timestamp column. This is quite easy with a T-SQL script scheduled with a SQL Agent job.

Comment: SQL Server does not retain this data anywhere else, if you want a permanent record of it the onus is on you to implement it. Take a look at [Brent Ozar's](https://www.brentozar.com/) free First Responder scripts which have built in logging to a table, you just need to schedule accordingly.